# Scrolling jQuery UI modal overlay not scrolling

Tags: jquery, css

I'm building a simple modal pop-up dialog box. The basics are working but I would like the dialog box to scroll, using the main page scrollbar to control it.

**I'm not sure if this is a jquery issue or a css issue.**

The effect I am after is like this: 
http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/328/index.php
(click on an image and then scroll the outer window scrollbar).

My code is here:
https://gist.github.com/sfcarroll/4739040

CSS:

```
#overlay {
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

#blanket {
  background-color: white;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.dialog {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: none;
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  height: 2000px;
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #F7F5F5;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.5);
```

}

I know the example I have given is using the colorbox plugin, but I am hoping this effect is possible with the standard jQuery UI.

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dEzMp/

Comment: Do you want your dialog stay in window while scrolling?

Comment: Yes, so the entire outer window scrolls (which is why I added all that lorum to the background).

Comment: I think giving `height: 100%` to `#overlay` would fix problem. If not, place an example to [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Thanks Morpheus. It didn't work but I did add it to jsfiddle. The outer windows scrolls but the modal dialog does not scroll with it.

Comment: Testing it now -- thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24193/discussion-between-seangeneva-and-morpheus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add bit of jQuery:

```
var postop = $('dialog').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
   $('.dialog').css('top', postop);
});
```

And change your `.dialog` div position:

```
.dialog {
   position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found exactly what I want as a Twitter Bootstrap extension.

http://jschr.github.com/bootstrap-modal/